# Abbreviation plugins

Tags: jquery, plugins

I need a good abbreviation plugin which I can use in a text area , using jquery.

Something like when user types `BP` in the text area,  it would show an expanded version like `blood pressure` and he must be able to accept or reject the expansion.

Comment: And what do you need this abbreviation plugin to do?

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/abbreviation ?

Comment: @Tomas Lycken - please see my changed original question.